# Jetpack compose: how to force a dropdownmenu to be anchored underneath its parent?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm currently using a `dropdownmenu` for selecting one of many options in my app. The problem is that the dropdownmenu expands above where it is originally anchored once it has many elements in it (see images attached). How can I force the drop down menu to stay anchored to the bottom of the button as in the first image? Thanks!

[what i want (only works with few items in the list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfYrd.png)

[the problem (occurs when there is lots of items in the list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xNz6.png)

Edit: here is the relevant code:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) { // box for dropdown menu
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = { showCategories = true }
                ) {
                    Icon(Icons.Default.Favorite, null)
                    Text("${currentCategory.name}")
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_expand_more_24),
                        contentDescription = "expand more"
                    )
                }
                DropdownMenu(
                    expanded = showCategories,
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        showCategories = false
                    }
                ) {
                    categories.forEach {
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            onClick = {
                                onCategoryChangeRequest(it)
                                showCategories = false
                            }
                        ) {
                            Text(it.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please provide some code that what you have done so far.

Comment: @Y.Kakdas I just added the relevant code. I based my implementation off of samples in the documentation. They state to use a box and then your dropdown menu should be anchored to the other composable in the box (the Button in my case). After doing some more reading of the DropDownMenu implementation, I think it expands to the bottom of the screen if it doesn't have enough space, and then towards the top of the screen if there still isn't enough. I just want it to remain anchored no matter what because it's a scrollable list after all and should remain anchored to the button it belongs to.

Comment: I don't think we can change it. Inside the `DropDownMenu` there is defined a `DropdownMenuPositionProvider`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Yeah I ended up copying the entire DropDownMenu implementation and then trying to write my own DropdownMenuPositionProvider but I wasn't able to get the behaviour I wanted. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a max size for your `DropdownMenu`.

```kotlin
DropdownMenu(
    modifier = Modifier.requiredSizeIn(maxHeight = 200.dp),
    ...
)
```

It worked for me...

[image]

Comment: Hi. I ended up doing this as a temporary solution as well (although I used Modifier.height(200.dp)), but I'd rather it expand until it hits the bottom of the screen, then not get any bigger, than use a hard-coded value like 200.dp. Any ideas on how to make it expand only until it reaches the bottom of the screen? Thanks.

Comment: I guess this is the better solution because, if you think about it, what would happen if the DropdownMenu was positioned at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Well it wouldn't expand at all, but I don't think it's wise to optimize for error cases. What I mean by that is my DropDownMenu is always set to be mid screen, and so it's safe to assume I won't need to account for the case you mentioned.